# Hover only works on half of the image

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to coding so I don't know what is going wrong... I have social media icons with a hover that is supposed to show up pink instead of white which I did by using a second image except the image is only showing up on the bottom half. Any ideas?

CCS:

```
a.twitter:hover {
    background-image: url('http://www.new.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/twitter1.png');
    background-position: 5px -20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="social"><a class="twitter" href="http://twitter.com/" title="Twitter" alt="twitter"><center><img src="http://www.new.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wtwitter.png" hspace="5"></a>
```

Comment: This is the part that determines the positioning of the image: `background-position: 5px -20px;`. Just fiddle with it until it's in the right spot. This is just a guess, but try `background-position: 5px 0;` instead.

Comment: The `<center>` element no longer exists and you didn't close your div  and image tags properly.

Comment: Got it! Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Alter your `background-position` property.

```
background-position: xpox  ypos;
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to change an image based on a hover it helps to make the non-hovered state use a background image as well. That way you simply need to have it change the background image on hover.

See the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dfhsps7d/

```
<style>
.social {
    background-color:grey;
}
a.twitter {
    background-image: url('http://www.new.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wtwitter.png');
    display:block;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
}
a.twitter:hover {
    background-image: url('http://www.new.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/twitter1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>

<div class="social">
    <a class="twitter" href="http://twitter.com/" title="Twitter" alt="twitter"></a>
</div>
```

Please note that the first `.social` class is purely for ease of viewing the white icon.